# Can I Flashbang a D.Va Calling Mech?

Tags: overwatch

1. McCree's *Flashbang* is a grenade which stuns anyone within the blast radius. Channeled ultimates differently interact with *Flashbang* hero-by-hero. For example, *Whole Hog* is cut out when the Roadhog is *Flashbang*ed, while Bastion's *Configuration: Tank* will not be cancelled (although its duration will be wasted while the *Flashbang* is active).
2. D.Va, while she lost her mech due to 'dying' once or *Self-destruct*ing her mech, can use her "ultimate" *Call Mech* to re-summon her mech.

Given those premises, here's my question.

1. Can McCree stun D.Va *Calling Mech* with his *Flashbang* and cancel it?
2. If the answer for the first question is "yes", will it register for the achievement "Whoa There!", which requires you to shutdown an enemy using their ultimate with a *Flashbang*?

Comment: You can flashbang a self destructing mech if she throws it at you and should be able to get the "Whoa There!" achievement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question: yes, the flashbang will stop D. Va from boarding a called MEKA.

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually set her ultimate charge to 0 (she can immediately press 'Q' if she survives the stun), so I don't think it counts for 'Whoa There!'. Not exactly sure, though, since I haven't been in that scenario from McCree's perspective.

Comment: What happens to the mech?

Comment: the same thing that I'm pretty sure happens to the mech if the D. Va dies while boarding it, it crumbles and falls away.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really test getting the achievement in a custom game with my friends, either. I can see if one of my friends needs the achievement this weekend and is willing to try to do this. If so, I will update this answer.